# Initialize variables in constructor or in declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When using ReactJS with TypeScript, is it better to initialize class variables in the constructor or when the class variable is being declared?  It works fine either way and the transpiled javascript looks the same either way.

```
export class MyClass extends React.Component<iProps, {}> {
      private myName: string = "Hello";

      constructor(props: iProps) {
         super(props);

         this.myName= "Hello";
      }
}
```

Comment: Both look wrong to me, since the point of props is that they are passed in once per render, rather than when the class is first constructed.

Comment: The initial props are passed to the ctor, so yeah both ways should work. There's probably no right/wrong here, but I always prefer to set the member values inside the ctor as it makes the code more understandable in my opinion.

Comment: @TomFenech - Yes, I removed the props from the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's exactly the same, for example:

```
class MyClass1 {
      private myName: string = "Hello";
}
```

Compiles to:

```
var MyClass1 = (function () {
    function MyClass1() {
        this.myName = "Hello";
    }
    return MyClass1;
}());
```

And:

```
class MyClass2 {
      private myName: string;

      constructor() {
         this.myName = "Hello";
      }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
var MyClass2 = (function () {
    function MyClass2() {
        this.myName = "Hello";
    }
    return MyClass2;
}());
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20MyClass1%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20myName%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22Hello%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyClass2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20myName%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myName%3D%20%22Hello%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

As you can see the compiled versions are identical (except for the class names).
So you can use which one you find more elegant.

As for react, you can use the props which are passed to the constructor.
When using es6  style classes with react components then your initial state is assigned in the constructor and not using the `getInitialState` method.
If your initial state is a function of the props then you'll need to use those in the constructor.